# How do I make a generic type alias?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a very long generic type name inside an included package called:

```
MySuperLongGenericTypeNameWithCarrots<SomeType, SomeType>
```

Now, I would like to create an alias to shorten the name, like:

```
MyShortname<SomeType, SomeType>
```

I've tried the following, but didn't manage to figure out how to do this:

```
type MyShortname<SomeType, SomeType> = MySuperLongGenericTypeNameWithCarrots<SomeType, SomeType>;
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your `MyShortname` type alias should be valid. What error are you getting? `SOmeType` might be with constraints and you should apply same constraints to `MySHortName`

Comment: @captain-yossarian Type `SomeTypeB` does not satisfy the constraint `keyof SomeTypeA`

Comment: I know you already got your answer, but you might still consider editing the code here to be a [mcve], since the code here doesn't declare `MySuperLongGenericTypeNameWithCarrots` and it is that declaration and the constraints on its type parameters that's giving you the problem.  Without that type definition, the problem you mention here isn't demonstrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
type MyShortname<SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB extends keyof SomeTypeA> = MySuperLongGenericTypeNameWithCarrots<SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB>;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just found the same solution myself, thanks to your comment. Credits to you!